# Colocar una imagen al lado del nombre del usuario

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

necesitaba ayuda en mi código. La cuestión es de que tengo en html esto:

```
<div class="sidebar">
            <div class="header-sidebar ">
                <img width="30px" height="30px" src="../../../public/img/chat.png" alt="">
            <h4>Mensajes</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="list-msg" >
                <ul class="list-group lista-items" v-for="items in users" :key="items.idusuario" v-on:click="openchat(items.idusuario)">
                    <li class="list-group-item">  {{items.nombreu}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="contenedor-msg" id="frm-chats">
            <div class="header-msg ">
            <h5 class="titulomsg ml-2" >
            <img v-bind:src="nombrechat.imagen"> {{nombrechat.nombreu}}
            </h5>

            </div>
```

y en javascript esto:

```
openchat:function(id) {


                this.msg.para=id
                this.msgs=[];
                this.allmsg.forEach(item=>{
               this.util(item);

            })


            this.users.forEach(user=>{
             if(user.idusuario==id){
               this.nombrechat=user; 
               console.log(this.nombrechat.imagen);

             }

            })
```

no tengo idea del porque no me coloca la imagen en la parte html si comprobando con el log si me jala la imagen de la db (en la db esta la ruta de la imagen y la imagen  la tengo en una carpeta)

Comment: Hola, deberías revisar tu pregunta, ¿con qué lenguaje estas trabajando? Parece que es Vue, pero no lo dejas claro. Tambien deberías intentar tabular bien el código para que sea mas legible. Si es posible, estaría bien que pusieras una url con un ejemplo (puedes usar esto https://codesandbox.io/ o algo similar)

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que utilizar 'require' para poder mostrar una imagen cuando utilizas v-bind:src, el valor de "nombrechat.imagen" debe ser por ejemplo --> require("../../../public/img/chat.png"). En tu BD debes cambiar el valor de las rutas de las imágenes agregándoles el require, el 'require' sigue siendo un String.